# why does it say zero instead of Deactivated?

Tags: batch-file, set

```
set /a wave1=0

set /a wave2=0

set /a wave3=1

set /a wave4=0

set /a wave5=0

set /a wave6=1

set /a wave7=0

set /a wave8=0


if %wave1%==1 set wwave1=ACTIVATED

if %wave1%==0 set wwave1=DEACTIVATED

if %wave2%==1 set wwave2=ACTIVATED

if %wave2%==0 set wwave2=DEACTIVATED

if %wave3%==1 set wwave3=ACTIVATED

if %wave3%==0 set wwave3=DEACTIVATED 

if %wave4%==1 set wwave4=ACTIVATED

if %wave4%==0 set wwave4=DEACTIVATED

if %wave5%==1 set wwave5=ACTIVATED

if %wave5%==0 set wwave5=DEACTIVATED 

if %wave6%==1 set wwave6=ACTIVATED

if %wave6%==0 set wwave6=DEACTIVATED

if %wave7%==1 set wwave7=ACTIVATED

if %wave7%==0 set wwave7=DEACTIVATED

if %wave8%==1 set wwave8=ACTIVATED

if %wave8%==0 set wwave8=DEACTIVATED

echo Type the number of the wave you like to change

echo Or press B to go back

echo       wave  ____       STATUS

echo -----------------------------------

echo     wave 1          %wwave1%

echo     wave 2          %wwave2%

echo     wave 3          %wwave3% 

echo     wave 4          %wwave4%

echo     wave 5          %wwave5%

echo     wave 6          %wwave6%

echo     wave 7          %wwave7%

echo     wave 8          %wwave8%
```

Comment: Uh... no, it doesn't.

Comment: Also, format your code. We complained about this last time, and it's starting to get embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* an answer to your question.

I suggest you to read about [Array management in Batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do set /a "wave%%i=^!(%%i%%3)"
set "val[0]=DEACTIVATED"
set "val[1]=ACTIVATED"

for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do for %%j in (!wave%%i!) do set "wwave%%i=!val[%%j]!"

echo Type the number of the wave you like to change
echo Or press B to go back
echo       wave  ____       STATUS
echo -----------------------------------
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do echo     wave %%i          !wwave%%i!
```